# How can I deserialize an object from an XML string? 

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize an object back from it's XML string using xmlSerializer.Deserialize() but the returned object is always blank (not null, but all the properties are null or 0). I can't work out what I'm doing wrong and yet I get no errors or exceptions.

```
string xml = "***my xml is here***";

XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Order));
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader);
Order order = (Order)ser.Deserialize(xmlReader);
xmlReader.Close();
stringReader.Close();
```

The source of Order.cs was generated from the XSD using the the xsd.exe tool.

Source of order.cs: http://www.nickgilbert.com/etc/1/Order.txt

Sample order XML: http://www.nickgilbert.com/etc/1/example-order.xml

Comment: I was going to paste the XML and source of Order.cs but I can't see how to attach files on here.

Comment: Can you post your Order class?

Comment: Just place the code in your question. But you shouldn't include the whole source, just a minimal code that has the same problem.

Comment: Don't attach files, copy/paste the relevant parts into the question.

Comment: It appears correct to me.  What does the the XML look like?  Do the properties have getters/setters?  How are you serializing Order?  Are you putting Serializable tags on your properties?

Comment: You don't need the XmlReader. Probably not the error but to be sure: `ser.Deserialize(stringReader)`

Comment: As an aside, ditch the xmlserializer and use the DataContractSerializer.  Better serializer overall.

Comment: @Will it depends; DCS lacks a lot of fine-grain xml control (elements, etc). DataContractSerializer has better *features* (callbacks, etc), but XmlSerializer has better xml control.

Comment: @MarcGravell: That can be a bad thing.  Good, if you don't control the xml, bad if you do; lots of rookies worrying about whether or not their xml is "pretty" have asked XmlSerializer questions here...  Uh, I believe I wasted a fair amount of time when I first used it doing the same.  Ergh.

Comment: @Will I worry more about "meets the spec" than "pretty" ;p And attributes are not exactly uncommon.

Comment: I've now posted the source of the Order.cs and XML.

Comment: @Nick: No you haven't, you have posted 2 links. Please read the comments.

Comment: @Henk Sorry if your browser does not support links.

Comment: @Nick: very funny. Answers here are not just to help you but to form a repository. How long will those files be available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample XML file (example-order.xml) uses the namespace `http://tempuri.org/OrderSchema.xsd` but the code generated by XSD (order.cs) defines all of the elements in the namespace `http://x-rm.com/wrightcottrell/cataloguecd/`.

You'll need these namespaces to match up in order for serialization to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you get an object back *at all* tells me that the object is public and has a public parameterless constructor (otherwise an exception would have been thrown). So, it is most-likely failing one of:

- deserialization members must be either public properties with public `get` and public `set`, or public (non-readonly) fields
- by default the member-names must be an exact match for xml *element* names, in the same xml-namespace as the parent element; finer control can be obtained via attributes (changing the name, using attributes, namespaces, etc)

Comment: I don't have a constructor for Order - I presume the values are populated by the Deserialize function rather than by the constructor?

Comment: @Nick yes you do; if you don't declare one, a public parameterless constructor is assumed by the compiler. Without a public parameterless constructor, it **would not work**.